# Tuleap .csv Import issue

Tags: export-to-csv, tuleap

i have created a project named demo in tuleap and we are using task and bug trackers for creating artifacts, now i decided to do some testing, hence i created a test project. The problem is that now i have exported a .csv file from task tracker in demo project and tried to import in a test project, and it is showing errors like artifact id is missing and so on, date format is incorrect.
I used the same set of templates in both the projects, can anyone tell me how to import a .csv file with correct format, because i want all the  artifact datas from demo project to be replicated in test project as well.

Answer (score 0):

well I am no expert in Tuleap. In fact Just started exploring the tool. One of your issue sounds similar to what i had encountered, so thought of providing some inputs.

The reason for getting the artifact id error could be because you are importing a csv file which you had exported from another tracker. Since it is exported, it would have the "artifact id" value as well in the csv, but while importing the same csv to a new tracker, it wont be expecting a "artifact id" value provided in the imported file, since all the data would be created from scratch. If any row has "artifact id" value, the import operation treats it as an update operation and if the "artifact id" is empty, then a new artifact would get created.